# Best practice to embed Vimeo video in Nextjs or Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, embed, vimeo, react-player

I'm making a website with Next.js and wanting to embed vimeo videos and wondering what is the most common practice to do it.

I've tried regular iframe, react-player, @u-wave/react-vimeo.

I realized @u-wave/react-vimeo gives me 410 error sometimes when I leave the page open long and react-player when it loads it flickers a bit (small first and then it gets bigger to its size) :(

410 error I get on @u-wave/react-vimeo:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to get any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have implemented Vimeo player:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Play } from "phosphor-react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player/lazy";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

export default function VideoPlayer() {
  const playerRef = useRef()

  return (
    <div className={styles.playerWrapper}>
      <ReactPlayer
        id="MyId"
        className={styles.reactPlayer}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        controls
        playing
        light="img/main-page/image.webp"
        playIcon={
          <Btn
            className={styles.btnSmall}
            bgColor="var(--ifm-btn-primary)"
            textColor="var(--ifm-text-black)"
            borderRadius={40}
            fontSize={20}
            px={25}
            py={25}
            style={{
              maxWidth: 361,
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              gap: 10
            }}
          >
            <Play weight="fill" color="--ifm-text-black" size={24} />
          </Btn>
        }
        url="https://vimeo.com/yourid"
      ></ReactPlayer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
//styles.module.css

.playerWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    /* Player ratio: 100 / (1280 / 720) */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 92px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.reactPlayer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btnSs {
    max-width: 361px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .btnSmall {
        width: 150px !important;
        font-size: 13px !important;
        padding: 4px 10px !important;
        gap: 0px !important;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 451px){
    .playerWrapper {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution:

```
  <div style={STYLES.videoIframeContainer}>
    <iframe
      title="vimeo-player"
      src={VIDEO_URL}
      width="640"
      height="360"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
      style={STYLES.videoIframe}
    >
    </iframe>
  </div>
```

const STYLES = {
videoIframeContainer: {
padding: '56.25% 0 0 0',
position: 'relative',
},
videoIframe: {
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
left: 0,
width: '100%',
height: '100%'
}
}

Comment: not working with vimeo

Comment: It says "vimeo.com refused to connect." on the embed